# is there a way to parent everything from another control BUT its location?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, position, parent

Nothing much to it, just a general question. I've searched for ages on the web but I can't find anything that answers my question.

is this possible? I want to parent one picturebox to another (which is below the one I want to parent) to allow the transparency to work properly for the top picturebox. But the picturebox's location changes off to somewhere off screen which is what I don't want.

If there is nothing like that, then are there any suggestions?

Currently I'm working with very small pictureboxes and I've tried everything to get the top image to be in the same place, including things like this code:

```
Btn_Close2.Location = New Point(Btn_Close2.Location.X - Btn_Close.Left, Btn_Close2.Location.Y - Btn_Close.Top)
```

But the top picturebox just wonder's off somewhere.